# R data.table efficient replication by group

Tags: r, data.table, replicate

I am running into some memory allocation problems trying to replicate some data by groups using data.table and rep.

Here is some sample data:

```
ob1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1999),c("THE","BLACK","DOG","JUMPED","OVER","RED","FENCE"),c(4)),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ob2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(2000),c("I","WALKED","THE","BLACK","DOG"),c(3)),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ob3 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(2001),c("SHE","PAINTED","THE","RED","FENCE"),c(1)),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ob4 <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(2002),c("THE","YELLOW","HOUSE","HAS","BLACK","DOG","AND","RED","FENCE"),c(2)),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
sample_data <- rbind(ob1,ob2,ob3,ob4)
colnames(sample_data) <- c("yr","token","multiple")
```

What I am trying to do is replicate the tokens (in the present order) by the multiple for each year.

The following code works and gives me the answer I want:

```
good_solution1 <- ddply(sample_data, "yr", function(x) data.frame(rep(x[,2],x[1,3])))

good_solution2 <- data.table(sample_data)[, rep(token,unique(multiple)),by = "yr"]
```

The issue is that when I scale this up to 40mm+ rows, I get into memory issues for both possible solutions.

If my understanding is correct, these solutions are essentially doing an rbind which allocates everytime.

Does anyone have a better solution?

I looked at set() for data.table but was running into issues because I wanted to keep the tokens in the same order for each replication.

Comment: Since version 1.9.2. (on CRAN 27 Feb 2014), `data.table` has gained a new function `setDT() ` which takes a `list` or `data.frame` and changes its type by reference to `data.table`, *without any copy*. So, `setDT(sample_data)` instead of `data.table(sample_data)` may help to save memory.

Answer (score 3):

One way is:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(sample_data)
# multiple seems to be a character, convert to numeric
dt[, multiple := as.numeric(multiple)]
setkey(dt, "multiple")
dt[J(rep(unique(multiple), unique(multiple))), allow.cartesian=TRUE]
```

Everything except the last line should be straightforward. The last line uses a subset using key column with the help of `J(.)`. For each value in `J(.)` the corresponding value is matched with "key column" and the matched subset is returned.

That is, if you do `dt[J(1)]` you'll get the subset where `multiple = 1`. And if you note carefully, by doing `dt[J(rep(1,2)]` gives you the same subset, but twice. Note that there's a difference between passing `dt[J(1,1)]` and `dt[J(rep(1,2)]`. The former is matching values of (1,1) with the *first-two-key-columns* of the data.table respectively, where as the latter is subsetting by matching (1 and 2) against the *first-key* column of the data.table.

So, if we were to pass the same value of the column 2 times in `J(.)`, then it gets be duplicated twice. We use this trick to pass 1 1-time, 2 2-times etc.. and that's what the `rep(.)` part does. `rep(.)` gives 1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4.

And if the join results in more rows than `max(nrow(dt), nrow(i))` (i is the rep vector that's inside `J(.)`), you've to explicitly use `allow.cartesian = TRUE` to perform this join (I guess this is a new feature from data.table 1.8.8).

---

**Edit:** Here's some benchmarking I did on a "relatively" big data. I don't see any spike in memory allocations in both methods. But I've yet to find a way to monitor peak memory usage within a function in R. I am sure I've seen such a post here on SO, but it slips me at the moment. I'll write back again. For now, here's a test data and some preliminary results in case anyone is interested/wants to run it for themselves.

```
# dummy data
set.seed(45)
yr <- 1900:2013
sz <- sample(10:50, length(yr), replace = TRUE)
token <- unlist(sapply(sz, function(x) do.call(paste0, data.frame(matrix(sample(letters, x*4, replace=T), ncol=4)))))
multiple <- rep(sample(500:5000, length(yr), replace=TRUE), sz)

DF <- data.frame(yr = rep(yr, sz), 
                 token = token, 
                 multiple = multiple, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Arun's solution
ARUN.DT <- function(dt) {
    setkey(dt, "multiple")
    idx <- unique(dt$multiple)
    dt[J(rep(idx,idx)), allow.cartesian=TRUE]
}

# Ricardo's solution
RICARDO.DT <- function(dt) {
    setkey(dt, key="yr")
    newDT <- setkey(dt[, rep(NA, list(rows=length(token) * unique(multiple))), by=yr][, list(yr)], 'yr')
    newDT[, tokenReps := as.character(NA)]

    # Add the rep'd tokens into newDT, using recycling
    newDT[, tokenReps := dt[.(y)][, token], by=list(y=yr)]
    newDT
}

# create data.table
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)

# benchmark both versions
require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(res1 <- ARUN.DT(DT), res2 <- RICARDO.DT(DT), replications=10, order="elapsed")

#                     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
# 1    res1 <- ARUN.DT(DT)           10   9.542    1.000     7.218    1.394
# 2 res2 <- RICARDO.DT(DT)           10  17.484    1.832    14.270    2.888
```

But as Ricardo says, it may not matter if you run out of memory. So, in that case, there has to be a trade-off between speed and memory. What I'd like to verify is the peak memory used in both methods here to say definitively if using `Join` is better.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, the character issue was just me being stupid while creating this sample data.

Comment: Do you think that this approach will use less memory?  I haven't implemented it for my large sample but I notice that it uses replicate as well.  What would the difference in your solution and my good_solution2?

Comment: It'll subset for each value in `J(.)` and keep joining. So, if you had 10 ids with 100 rows each and multiple of 4, then you'll get 10*100*4 = 4000 rows (100 rows in each subset).

Comment: I suspect Ricardo's solution maybe your answer in that case (after reading your question again). I'd just benchmark the two methods on a relatively bigger data (but not too big that you accidentally run out of memory and crash your R-session, but clear enough to distinguish the fastest approach + memory-cautious approach).

Comment: I love benchmarking, but i'm not sure if that will be a clear indication of the better approach.  I think ultimately there will have to be a sacrifice of speed to accomplish the goal effectively

Comment: +1 towards that silver `data.table` tag :-) for the great explanation which is helping me learn

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, I suspect yours will be "faster" if the binding happens without preallocation. But since `data.table` spits out the error that there are 66 rows (in this case) unless you use `allow.cartesian=TRUE`, I wonder if there will a performance difference. If there is a difference, we should be able to see it as the object is being copied every time (akin to for-loop pre-allocation, I suppose). I'll try to figure it out and get back.

Comment: @SimonO101, thanks. I'll try to make a comparison and see if it could be improved.

Comment: @Brad, I tested with a data.frame of dim=3482*3 with multiples ranging from 500 to 2000. The output was 9 million rows. And it worked fine for me. And there wasn't memory difference between Ricardo's and mine (but this is very premature as I was looking at the system monitor and not actually measuring). But for sure, `join` is faster (0.7 vs 1.9 seconds)! So, it'd be great if you could benchmark on your data (also, what's the size of your data.frame?) and report back. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can try allocating the memory for all the rows first, and then populating them iteratively.
eg:

```
  # make sure `sample_data$multiple` is an integer
  sample_data$multiple <- as.integer(sample_data$multiple)

  # create data.table
  S <- data.table(sample_data, key='yr')

  # optionally, drop original data.frame if not needed
  rm(sample_data)

  ## Allocate the memory first
  newDT <- data.table(yr = rep(sample_data$yr, sample_data$multiple), key="yr")
  newDT[, tokenReps := as.character(NA)]

  # Add the rep'd tokens into newDT, using recycling
  newDT[, tokenReps := S[.(y)][, token], by=list(y=yr)]
```

---

#### Two notes:

(1)  `sample_data$multiple` is currently a character and thus getting coerced when passed to `rep` (in your original example).  It might be worth double-checking your real data if that is also the case.

(2)  I used the following to determine the number of rows needed per year

```
S[, list(rows=length(token) * unique(multiple)), by=yr]
```

Comment: Ricardo, it's character because he uses `cbind` and `as.data.frame` to create the data. And `cbind(.)` creates a matrix which is then wrapped around with `as.data.frame`. Since there's no `data.frame` input to `cbind` it is a matrix and so every value is converted to `character`.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo and Arun.  Ricardo, you have tokenReps and tokenRep in your code, which is giving the final answer and extra column.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, your first allocation step is just: `newDT <- data.table(yr = rep(sample_data$yr, sample_data$multiple), key="yr")`, isn't it?

Comment: @Arun, indeed!  And that is quite a bit faster and cleaner.  Edited my answer to reflect, thanks!